# After switching adapter of ListView, wrong indexes are selected ("greyed out") Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-listview

I'm new to this. After long click on item in ListView item's background turns grey. My list has many items (it expands below the display) so I had to remember indexes of "grey" items and then in custom adapter I had to check their position with list of those selected indexes (then I decide which layout to set up in getView function).

But now, when I'm searching (==filtering) across items in my ListView, I  do get like "old indexes", so no items with original value are selected, but these items that NOW have their old indexes (but different values.) I'm also switching an adapter while filtering (how you can see below in code example).

MainActivity.kt onCreate fun:

```
readFile()
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener { parent, view, index, id ->
            var indexValue = enPairs[index]
            Log.d("david", "Notify long clicked")
            if (index in selectedItems) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                selectedItems.remove(index)
                enWords.remove(indexValue.mainWordSplit)
                enDefns.remove(indexValue.defnSplit)
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e3e3e3"))
                selectedItems.add(index)
                enWords.add(indexValue.mainWordSplit)
                enDefns.add(indexValue.defnSplit)
            }
            true
        }
        var adapter = UserListAdapter(this, enPairs, selectedItems)
        listView?.adapter = adapter

        searchText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                var searchFilter = enPairs.filter { searchText.text.toString() in it.mainWordSplit }
                var searchAdapter = UserListAdapter(this@MainActivity, searchFilter, selectedItems)
                listView?.adapter = searchAdapter
            }
        })
```

UserListAdapter.kt getView fun:

```
class UserListAdapter(private var activity: Activity, private var items: List<UserDto>, private var selected: ArrayList<Int>): BaseAdapter() {
    private class ViewHolder(row: View?) {
        var txtName: TextView? = null
        var txtComment: TextView? = null

        init {
            this.txtName = row?.findViewById(R.id.txtName)
            this.txtComment = row?.findViewById(R.id.txtComment)
        }
    }

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view: View?
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        if (position in selected){
            val inflater = activity?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_row_selected, null)
            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
            view?.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            val inflater = activity?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_row, null)
            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
            view?.tag = viewHolder
        }


        val userDto = items[position]
        viewHolder.txtName?.text = userDto.mainWordSplit
        viewHolder.txtComment?.text = userDto.defnSplit

        return view as View
    }
.
.
.
}
```

[Before searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbale.png)
[While searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64raW.png)

Any ideas how to make my selected items stay selected?

Comment: You need to change whatever your userDto type is to also contain a unique ID and instead of judging whether item is selected or not by its position in a list, you do that by looking up its ID.

Comment: Worked just fine :)